# Request post pasing JSON using cherrypy python

Tags: javascript, python, json, cherrypy

I am trying send json in request post to python using cherrypy. When I send the request, the response is (400 bad request, Invalid JSON document), nevertheless using postman i make the same request and the server return the result withou errors.

My python code:

```
import time, sys, cherrypy, os
import json
import ML_Training
import ML_Unsup_Predictor_Results

class Application(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    @cherrypy.tools.json_in()
    def predict(self):
        try:
            cherrypy.response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
            cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
            input_json = cherrypy.request.json
            r = ML_Unsup_Predictor_Results.Predict_New_Values(input_json["model"], input_json["value"])
            return json.dumps(r)
        except Exception as e:
            print e.message
            return e.message
```

In javascript my request post using angularjs

```
$http.post(mlService.getMlMultitenancyOrigin() + '/python/predict',
           {"model":$scope.params[2], "value": arr}).then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
})
```

note: the structure of arr is arr = [1,2,3,4] (array of integers)

My question is why "invalid JSON"

attached image of postmant, when the result is ok

[image: postman screenshot]

Comment: You may also use `@cherrypy.tools.json_out()` and return dict instead of converting in to JSON manually.

Comment: Regarding sending raw JSON data via POST request with jQuery, remember to stringify the object first: `JSON.stringify({"model":$scope.params[2], "value": arr})`